# Как узнать сколько времени (именно минут) прошло?

Tags: javascript

Есть две даты:

```
date1=Wed Jan 22 2020 13:17:24 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)
date2=Thu Jan 23 2020 15:42:23 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)
```

Как определить сколько минут прошло?

Comment: Создать два объекта Date, вычесть один из другого и поделить на 60000

Answer (score 1):

```
let date1 = 'Wed Jan 22 2020 13:10:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)';
let date2 = 'Wed Jan 22 2020 13:20:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)';

console.log((new Date(date2).getTime() - new Date(date1).getTime())/60000)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var date1 = new Date("Wed Jan 22 2020 13:17:24 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)")
var date2 = new Date("Thu Jan 23 2020 15:42:23 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)")

console.log(Math.floor((date2 - date1) / 1000 / 60))
```